# Using FIPS enabled endpoints of AWS Elasticache

Tags: redis, amazon-elasticache, fips

I'm trying to enable FIPS for Elasticache Redis.
AWS Elasticache documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/elasticache-compliance.html#elasticache-compliance-fedramp) says "Your ElastiCache for Redis clusters can be created using the FIPS endpoints available - us-east-1 - elasticache-fips.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
But there is no reference on how to configure this. There is no sample available.
Anyone has done this? Any ideas on how to mention this in CloudFormation templates?

Answer (score 0):

The way to use FIPS endpoints in AWS is documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#FIPS-endpoints)

As documented, there are 3 options:

1. Set the `AWS_USE_FIPS_ENDPOINT` environment variable to `true`.
2. Add `use_fips_endpoint=true` to your `~/.aws/config` file
3. The AWS Command Line Interface supports these mechanisms, and also provides the `--endpoint-url` option.

An example of option 3:

```
aws elasticache describe-replication-groups \
    --region us-east-1 \
    --endpoint-url https://elasticache-fips.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```